# Printing string arrays to UILabels

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any way to print out an Array of Strings to an UILabel without any special characters, i.e. ["number1","number2","number3"]

I want it to look like this in my UILabel Output:

```
number1
number2
number3
```

Here is my code:

```
let addInputs = quantityField.text! + "x " + descriptionField.text!   
var listArray: [String] = []
listArray.append("\(addInputs)")

for addInputs in listArray {
            //itemListLabel.text = "\n\(addInputs)"
            print("\(addInputs)")
            itemListLabel.text = "\(listArray)"
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can join the items together with `\n` to add a hard return:

```
itemListLabel.text = listArray.joinWithSeparator("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do 2 things:

```
itemListLabel.numberOfLines = listArray.count
itemListLabel.text = listArray.joinWithSeparator("\n")
```

The first line sets the number of lines to display in the label. If you know beforehand what you want, you can just set this in Interface Builder. The second line joins the array of strings with a new-line separator between each.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.3**

`itemListLabel.text = listArray.joined(separator: "\n")`